# Flutter: Trying to make a button out of a png with an effect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

1. List item

Trying to make a button-based off an image of a dog, that when clicked, spawns a png of a new dog. Got the button working but nothing I try will make the new dog show up. I've looked over my code tons of times and don't see whats wrong with it. Any help would be massively appreciated.

the code in question

```
          child: FlatButton( 
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            onPressed: () {
              debugPrint('button clicked');
```

Image.asset(display);

```
            },

            child: null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You have the `Image.asset(display)` assigned to nothing.

You need to replace the `child: null` by `child: display != null ? Image.asset(display) : null`

Also, you need to call the **answerQuestion** method inside the `onPress`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **state** and to change state use basically **setState((){})** method

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}
 
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 
    final String display1 = 'assets/doggy.png';
 final String display2 = 'assets/poochie.png';
    bool isFirstImage=true;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo 006'),),
        body: Center(
            child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              width: 220.0,
              height: 220.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(isFirstImage?display1:display2),
                ),
              ),
              child: FlatButton( 
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                onPressed: () {
                 
setState((){isFirstImage=!isFirstImage;});

                },
 
                child: null,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```